# Creating a class mimic ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a class that mimic some of the `ArrayList<Integer>` behavior.

I used `int[] arr1` to store the element of the array and `int[] tempArr` a temp storage while I am trying to increase the capacity or the original array `arr1`

This not work. So what do you think the other approach I can use.

Here is my code: see  `public void add`

```
public class ArrayListLike implements ArrayListLikeInterface {


    public int capacity = 0; // The capacity of the array list (ArrayListLike)
    private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 10; // Initial capacity
    private int size = 0;  // Initial size
    private int[] arr;
    private int[] tempArr;
    private int count = 0;


    // Constructors
    public ArrayListLike() {
        arr = new int[INIT_CAPACITY];
        capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;
    }



    public void add(Integer element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (count == capacity) {
            tempArr = new int[capacity];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tempArr,0, capacity);
            capacity *= 2;
            arr = null;
            arr = new int[capacity];
            System.arraycopy(tempArr, 0, arr,0, capacity);
            arr[count] = element;
            count++;
        } else {
            arr[count] = element;
            count++;
        }
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (index <=  capacity) {
            return arr[index];
        } else {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        size = arr.length;
        return size;
    }


}
```

Here is the main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ArrayListLike arr1 = new ArrayListLike();
        System.out.println(arr1.size());

        arr1.add(0);
        arr1.add(1);
        arr1.add(2);
        arr1.add(3);
        arr1.add(4);
        arr1.add(5);
        arr1.add(6);
        arr1.add(7);
        arr1.add(8);
        arr1.add(9);
        arr1.add(10);
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 10
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at hw5sol.ArrayListLike.add(ArrayListLikeInterface.java:31)
    at hw5sol.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Comment: what doesn't work? it throws you an exception? Please elaborate

Comment: If you want to mimic `ArrayList` the first thing you you is *implement* the same interfaces!

Comment: @mckuok I add the main class and the error.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I am not trying to mimic everything, I am also try to do that fro scratch with my own interfaces.

Comment: At the very least you are putting N elements into your temp array and then your are trying to retrieve 2N out of the same array into the newly expanded space

Comment: @OlegSklyar Thank you. The issue was with capacity it's twice the size of the temp array.

Comment: Well yes, as posted above and in the answer below, but really this site and brains of its visitors should not be used in place of the standard unit test and a debugger. You would not spend ages looking for answer and would not need to post any question here if you had written a trivial good case test and ran it with a debugger!

Comment: @OlegSklyar I am one of the site visitor, if someone ask the same question and I know the answer I will be glad to help them. No body has the right to say what this site visitors brains should be used for. Actually no body has the right to say whatever brain except his own brain should be used for. Goodbye.

Comment: @Yamona I pointed you towards the direction of your error (which you have appreciated) even though you clearly did not do your home work. This website has certain policies, which IMO you did not adhere to, but beyond policies there is a certain expectation from the community for the quality of questions, widely discussed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging You can remain offended as long or as much as you like, but you are clearly mistaken that community members cannot clearly state deficiencies of your questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're copying old array to new array, you use the new capacity size, which is 20 and `temp` has only 10 elements, therefore an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown when it tries to copy next elements.

```
public void add(Integer element) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (count == capacity) {
        tempArr = new int[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tempArr,0, capacity);
        capacity *= 2;
        arr = null;
        arr = new int[capacity];
//Here!!
        System.arraycopy(tempArr, 0, arr,0, tempArr.length);
        arr[count] = element;
        count++;
    } else {
        arr[count] = element;
        count++;
    }
}
```